# PHP rsort function returns incorrect ordering

Tags: php

I'm trying to sort my array values in descending order, but PHP sorted incorrectly.
Here is my code example:

```
<?php $scores = array('98%','90%', '85%','100%','74%');
   rsort($scores);
   foreach($scores AS $key=>$val){
     echo $key.'=>'.$val.'<br/>';
   }
?>
```

And the result is:

```
0=>98%
1=>90%
2=>85%
3=>74%
4=>100%
```

But I want it to be like this:

```
0=>100%
1=>98%
2=>90%
3=>85%
4=>74%
```

I was also tried others sorting functions, but still cannot get the correct result.

Comment: I think the problem is that you sort strings instead of integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
rsort($scores,SORT_NUMERIC);
```

Instead of:

```
rsort($scores);
```

Comment: Thanks Dave. I chose this method and it works for me now.

Answer (score 2):

You can try like below:

```
$scores = array('98%','90%', '85%','100%','74%');

var_dump($scores);
rsort($scores, SORT_NUMERIC );

var_dump($scores);
```

Here is my test online:
[enter link description here](https://eval.in/637584)

I hope to solve your problem:

Answer (score 0):

try this,use only [**sort**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) function

```
$scores = array('98%','90%', '85%','100%','74%');
sort($scores);   
foreach($scores AS $key=>$val){
     echo $key.'=>'.$val.'<br/>';
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://3v4l.org/eOL0h)